How to make a level indicator like this picture in flutter?

I have successfully made the custom shape on the right with clipPath but I need help with the left side indicator that indicates which level the user is and also indicates the upcoming levels of the rewards.

My first thought would be to create a container with a height as long as the screen. Let's say that's 1000 pixels high and 40 pixels wide. (This is the vertical bar)
Then, if you, let's say, have 100 levels, I would divide the height of the vertical bar into 100 pieces and place every small part of the level number circle indicator on every piece. To do this, you can use a Stack where you place inside the Stack your vertical bar, and on top of this, you position every level indicator.
check here how you can use stack https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flutter-stack-widget/

Thanks. I used a similar logic and built it.

@PramitLikhanSarker If this helped you, or you think it was a good answer. please accept it as an answer

What if i have dynamic text (can short or very long text) instead of number ?
